# getting information from a website in processing?

Tags: html, processing

I am currently making a processing program, where a part of it will be to acess some information from at website. The website will be an HTML file, where some information is stored, which i need to acess and parse. I know how to open a html file, but my problem is that it is supposed to acess a list, which is generated after a login on the website. How do i do that?

This is the website, right after loading the HTML file:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIVFI.png

After a login, the website will begin to spit out data every two seconds. 
I wanna acess the data in the ordered list, and i wanna acess it every two seconds in my processing program. How do i do that?

This is the website, after a login, after a moment.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgzHz.png

Comment: What you 'wanna' do is read the tour section of this website so your posts do not get deleted: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Figure out how the authentication system works and then make sure to supply required session data for every request.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a web browser to submit a login, you're really interacting with the server. Usually the web browser submits a `POST` request containing the login information (like a username and password), and the server responds with the next webpage to load.

The details of this are going to depend on the website you're interacting with. Some websites might use AJAX to submit the data and then trigger some JavaScript to run.

The point is, you're going to have to understand exactly how the underlying web server and webpage works. Then you're going to have to use the rules of those interactions to issue the appropriate requests from your Processing code.

It *might* be as simple as submitting the login credentials in the url itself and then just scraping the information from the webpage.

More likely, you're going to have to interact with some kind of web API and do the requests yourself. Google "Java post request" for more info.

Of course, all of this assumes that the website is open to people using it. If this website isn't yours, it could also be locked down and unavailable to you.